# How to convert html to JSX, ReactJS Component?

Tags: javascript, html, redux, reactjs

I am using Webpack, Redux and ReactJS.

Currently I have the following set up in my `index.html` but I want to convert it to JSX, ReactJS Component. What's the proper and correct way to do so?

And in my `index.html` `<head/>`, have a class helper functions called `classie.js`:

```
<script src="classie.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
          var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
              shrinkOn = 300,
              header = document.querySelector("header");
          if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
              classie.add(header,"smaller");
          } else {
              if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                  classie.remove(header,"smaller");
              }
          }
      });
  }
  window.onload = init();
</script>
```

And in my `index.html` `<body/>`:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
      <div class="container clearfix">
          <h1 id="logo">
              Practice Navigation Bar
          </h1>
          <nav>
            <a href="">Button 1</a>
            <a href="">Button 2</a>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

So convert it into like the following ReactJS component format:

```
//App.js 

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import actions from '../redux/actions'

class NavBar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {/*e.g. What should go in here?*/}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(NavBar)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I'm going to make a couple of assumptions here. One, that you'll be using React Router. Two, that the header is sitewide, and the remaining content is dependent on the route/path.

Also note that I'm throwing most of the html that you provided into a single header component. But, depending on the complexity of the header, you could break that down even further into a nav component and/or a navlink component.

**Index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';

function App({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { has, add, remove } from '../classie';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      display: false,
    };

    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        shrinkOn = 300,
        header = document.querySelector("header");
      if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
        add(header, "smaller");
      } else {
        if (has(header, "smaller")) {
          remove(header, "smaller");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  getData() {
    // GET request here
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.setState({
      display: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <div class="container clearfix">
          <h1 id="logo" onClick={this.doSomething}>
            Practice Navigation Bar
          </h1>
          <nav>
            <a href="">Button 1</a>
            <a href="">Button 2</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import InnerPage from './components/InnerPage';

module.exports = render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="innerpage" component={InnerPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Those are correct assumptions! Where should the `classie.js` go, which used to be in my `index.html` `<head/>`?

Comment: Just checking to see if you saw my previous comment. Please let me know

Comment: It depends what you're doing. Generally, you keep everything related to the component inside the component to keep it modular. Although I also typically have helper files and such that get bundled up and inserted into the build html using Webpack (that's a much more in-depth answer). I've updated the header component example here to give you a couple of ideas. One uses React's lifecycle methods (componentDidMount) to trigger an API request, and the other changes the state of the component when the logo is clicked.

Comment: Really appreciate the clarification. Where am I supposed to call the `classie.js` and keep the file? And how about as for the function `init() {...}` in `index.html`? Should I include it in the `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Updated my example to answer those questions.

Comment: Makes sense! So I made the attempt with what you provided, but I got the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: classie is not defined` inside the componentDidMount(). Also, in the `index.html` file, `<script src="classie.js"></script>` is not needed anymore, correct?

Comment: Got it to work! One last question before I accept the answer. How would I create a divider at the bottom of the navigation bar? And have it disappear once `classie` calls the `.smaller`?

Comment: Just checking to see if you saw my last comment. Please let me know.